# Not update Table after saving or updating Core data - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have bellow class for my `CRUD` in my project:

```
class ProjectCoreDataStore: DegreesProtocol, DegreesStoreUtilityProtocol {

    // MARK: - Managed object contexts
    var mainManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    var privateManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext

    // MARK: - Object lifecycle

    init()
    {

        //let fileName: String = "PortalMDBApp.sqlite"
        let fileName: String = "MDB.sqlite"

        let fileManager:FileManager = FileManager.default
        let directory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

        let documentUrl = directory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        let bundleUrl = Bundle.main.resourceURL?.appendingPathComponent(fileName)

        // here check if file already exists on simulator
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: (documentUrl.path)) {
            //Document file exists!
            //return documentUrl.path
        }else if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: (bundleUrl?.path)!) {
            //Document file does not exist, copy from bundle!
            try! fileManager.copyItem(at:bundleUrl!, to:documentUrl)
        }

        // MARK: - After pass sqlite to device then run bellow code

        // This resource is the same name as your xcdatamodeld contained in your project.
        guard let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MDB", withExtension: "momd") else {
            fatalError("Error loading model from bundle")
        }

        // The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        guard let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL) else {
            fatalError("Error initializing mom from: \(modelURL)")
        }

        let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom)
        mainManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        mainManagedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc

        let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let docURL = urls[urls.endIndex-1]
        /* The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file.
         This code uses a file named "DataModel.sqlite" in the application's documents directory.
         */
        let storeURL = docURL.appendingPathComponent("MDB.sqlite")
        do {
            try psc.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: storeURL, options: nil)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Error migrating store: \(error)")
        }

        privateManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        privateManagedObjectContext.parent = mainManagedObjectContext
    }

    deinit
    {
        do {
            try self.mainManagedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Error deinitializing main managed object context")
        }
    }

    // MARK: - CRUD operations - Generic enum result type

    func updateLanguageDB(idLang: String,
                          completionHandler: @escaping (() throws -> String) -> Void) {

        privateManagedObjectContext.perform {
            //MARK: Clear selectedLang
            do {
                let clears = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ShortMajorTBL")
                let query = NSPredicate(format: "(%K = %@)",
                                        "identifier","L100")
                clears.predicate = query
                let results = try self.privateManagedObjectContext.fetch(clears)
                let resultData = results as! [ShortMajorTBL]
                for object in resultData {
                    object.isSelected = "false"
                }
                do {
                    try self.privateManagedObjectContext.save()
                }catch{
                }
                completionHandler{return "SeuccesClear"}
            } catch {
                completionHandler { throw DegreesStoreError.CannotFetch("Cannot fetch orders") }
            }

            //MARK: Update selectedLang
            do {
                let updateRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ShortMajorTBL")
                let query = NSPredicate(format: "(%K = %@) AND (%K = %@) AND (%K = %@)",
                                        "isSelected","false",
                                        "langId",idLang.uppercased(),
                                        "identifier","L100")
                updateRequest.predicate = query
                let results = try self.privateManagedObjectContext.fetch(updateRequest)
                let resultData = results as! [ShortMajorTBL]
                for object in resultData {
                    object.isSelected = "true"
                }
                do {
                    try self.privateManagedObjectContext.save()
                }catch{
                }
                completionHandler{return "SeuccesUpdate"}
            } catch {
                completionHandler { throw DegreesStoreError.CannotFetch("Cannot fetch orders") }
            }
        }
    }


    func fetchListSelectedLangShortTermDB(completionHandler: @escaping (() throws -> [ShortMajorTBL]) -> Void){
        privateManagedObjectContext.perform {
            do{
                let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ShortMajorTBL")
                let query = NSPredicate(format: "(%K = %@) AND (%K = %@)",
                                        "isSelected","true",
                                        "identifier","L100")
                fetchRequest.predicate = query
                let results = try self.privateManagedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [ShortMajorTBL]
                for ss in results{
                    print("1 >>> \(ss.idLang)")
                }
            }catch{
            }

        do{
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ShortMajorTBL")
            let query = NSPredicate(format: "(%K = %@) AND (%K = %@)",
                                    "isSelected","true",
                                    "identifier","L100")
            fetchRequest.predicate = query
            let results = try self.privateManagedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [ShortMajorTBL]
            for ss in results{
                print("1 >>> \(ss.idLang)")
                print("1 >>> \(ss.id)")
            }
        }catch{
        }
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem:** I am using from this `func updateLanguageDB` for update records and when I test with bellow `query` in `func updateLanguageDB` say me that the update is success:

```
do{
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ShortMajorTBL")
    let query = NSPredicate(format: "(%K = %@) AND (%K = %@)",
                            "isSelected","true",
                            "identifier","L100")
    fetchRequest.predicate = query
    let results = try self.privateManagedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [ShortMajorTBL]
    for ss in results{
        print("1 >>> \(ss.id)")
    }
}catch{
}
```

But when I use from above `query` in other page do't get me any result??!!

And here is my `fun`:

```
func fetchListSelectedLangShortTermDB(completionHandler: @escaping (() throws -> [ShortMajorTBL]) -> Void){
    privateManagedObjectContext.perform {
        do{

            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ShortMajorTBL")
            let query = NSPredicate(format: "(%K = %@) AND (%K = %@)",
                                    "isSelected","true",
                                    "identifier","L100")
            fetchRequest.predicate = query
            let results = try self.privateManagedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [ShortMajorTBL]
            print("1 ++++ \(results.count)")
            for ss in results{
                print("1 >>> \(ss.idLang)")
                print("1 >>> \(ss.id)")
            }
        }catch{
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `xcdatamodeld` and `debug sqlite` :

[image]

And:
[image]

And: [image]

**Notic** When I fetch my `sqlite` from device I don't see any update record.

Comment: In your functions you have a do/catch inside another do/catch but it is only the outer that has any error handling so if `try self.privateManagedObjectContext.save()` throws an error it is ignored and `completionHandler{return "SeuccesUpdate"}` will incorrectly be called. So remove the inner do/catch everywhere so you actually calls the completion handler with an error if the save fails.

Comment: I updated my question, you can see it.

Comment: That is completely irrelevant to my comment, did you read it? Look everywhere in your code where you call `try self.privateManagedObjectContext.save()`

Comment: @ Joakim Danielson. I insert print in all of catch and don't get any error.

Comment: Ok, then I suggest you debug your code to try and find out what is going on and verify that way that something really gets updated.

Comment: You should review your predicate formatting in your `query` property in your `func fetchListSelectedLangShortTermDB`. You’re asking an `NSPredicate` to assess a property of type `bool` (`isSelected`) against a `String` (“true”) and using string placeholder `%@`. It’s a type mismatch - this will never be `== true`. So what placeholder do you use for type `bool`?

Comment: @ andrewbuilder. See my update question, please. Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `privateManagedObjectContext` and just use from `mainManagedObjectContext`, good work now. And removed `Z_PK` from primary status.