# IN clause in Core data - Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

How can I have a `query` with one `key` and multiple `value` for `key`, like:

```
langId IN (SELECT idLang FROM ShortMajorTBL WHERE isSelected = true) AND identifier = S300 AND isSelected = true
```

I set this `query` but not work:

```
let query = NSPredicate(format: "(%K = %@) AND (%K = %@) AND (%K in (%@))",
                        "isSelected","true",
                        "identifier","S300",
                        "idLang" , idLang)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Core Data Predicate IN Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652555/swift-core-data-predicate-in-clause)

Comment: If you read the answer on that question on how to set up in clause that might help.

Comment: jo jo, I refer you to my comment to your [previous core data question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57833135/1883707)... the comment still applies.Your predicate contains a type mismatch. What placeholder do you use for type `Bool`? Also I note that you have three keypaths (`%K`) in your `NSPredicate`, not one.

Comment: @ andrewbuilder. my type of isSelected is String id db, thank's a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my problem:

```
let query = NSPredicate(format: "(%K = %@) AND (%K = %@) AND (%K IN %@)",
                                        "isSelected","true",
                                        "identifier","S300",
                                        "langId" , idLang)
```

I edited `idLang` to `langId`.